# Prod build in Ionic 3 is changing the component name

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

ionic cordova build android --prod changes the component name to some random character like 't'. It's the uglification of JS code that produces a light weighted build. Awesome!!

But I am facing a issue in my code where I have to do some stuff specifically on some screens. I have some checks on those screen. After uglification name of the component changes and my checks are failing.

```
    ....
    this.app.viewWillEnter.subscribe(viewCtrl => {
       let indexFoundOn = 
       this.withFooterPages.indexOf(viewCtrl.component.name);
       // here I to have find component by name but name gets uglified on --prod release
        ....
    });
```

I am looking for any index type of property on ctrl that will not change on uglification. Unable to find it in the doc 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/